# Does Meteor.methods() preserve causality?

Tags: meteor

Can I assume that calls to Meteor methods will be executed on the server exactly in the order that they have been posted on the client? In other words: do Meteor methods preserve causality?

EDIT: Whatever the answer - this should probably go into the documentation unless I overlooked it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a given client/server connection, the server processes messages (method calls, sub/unsub requests, etc) from the client in order. The server does not start processing message N+1 until one of two things happens:

- It completes processing message N. For methods this means that the method body finishes running. For subscriptions this means that the publish handler finishes running.
- Message N is a method invocation, and the method body calls `this.unblock`.

(One could imagine relaxing these restrictions in the future, so that multiple subscribe methods could be processed in parallel, eg.)

Comment: David, thanks for the explanation. That is the assumption I was going with, but I'm confused in my example why the console.log on the server is not first-third-second given my `this.unblock` call in my second method?

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: I thought the below was correct, but I haven't been able to confirm it yet in my code. I'd like to get some more input from the meteor core group.

That said, these were my original thoughts:

If you invoke the method on the server **without** using `this.unblock`, the function will run synchronously and therefore block all other server-side calls. This is the *only* scenario where you could guarantee the order of the `Meteor.method` calls. [The docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) give a good overview.

Otherwise, with `this.unblock` the methods will run asynchronously on the server and therefore you will have no ordering guarantee.

BUT, I have yet to confirm this in my code. Regardless of the `this.unblock` in the server side code, the console logs the messages in first-second-third order. On the server, I would expect the order to be first-third-second.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        first: function() {
            console.log("server first");
            return "right away";
        },
        second: function () {
            this.unblock();
            for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {}
            console.log("server second");
            return "second one";
        },
        third: function () {
            console.log("server third");
            return "last";
        },
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        Meteor.call("first", function(error, result) {
            console.log("first completed: " + result);
        });
        Meteor.call("second", function(error, result) {
            console.log("second completed: " + result);
        });
        Meteor.call("third", function (error, result) {
            console.log("third completed: " + result);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: [I asked about this in the google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/MYa6U-KihVQ/8NBPb3mjxk0J).

Comment: Thanks! Will you update your answer here, once you got a response?

Comment: I certainly will sir :) FYI -- David Glasser who posted above is one of the core devs. You can follow the comment thread there for updates.

Comment: This is still single-threaded JavaScript. Calling `unblock` allows the server to process more messages... but it still has to actually get to the code that processes the message, eg by yielding. If you insert `Meteor._sleepForMs(1)` after the `this.unblock`, you should see third before second. (This call uses Fibers to yield for 1 ms, and during that yield the event loop will run and bring in the next message.) Database calls will also yield, so the typical use of unblock will involve calling unblock and then doing a Mongo call.

Comment: Thanks David. Really appreciate the insight. Your answer makes me happy.